# Dialogflow, Google Assistant: Getting error "MalformedResponse 'final_response' must be set"

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have three intents, "Cold Exposure", "Poisoning" and "Frostbite". Each intent has suggestion chips to move to the next intent, i.e. the "Cold Exposure" shows a chip of "Poisoning" and "Poisoning" shows a suggestion chip of "Frostbite".

All are follow up intents of the Default Welcome Intent, so all have the "Default Welcome Intent- followup" input context.

My problem is, when I call Cold Exposure and then call Poisoning, there's no problem. However, when I call Cold Exposure and then Poisoning, and then Frostbite, I get an error "MalformedResponse 'final_response' must be set." . Im not able to call any three intents back to back. I really dont know why this is happening.Im using v2 API.

This is the only error I have in my program, so it would be great if this could be solved quick.[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnFZs.png) is a screenshot of my intents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the lifespan of the "Default Welcome Intent- followup" output context in the Default Welcome Intent?
By default, when you create followup Intents, the output context lifespan set in the root Intent is 2. Each action decrements this count and the context disappears when the count reaches 0.

Try increasing the lifespan (in the grey circle next to the output context name) to something like 10 (or any other number you see fit) and remove it manually when needed in later intents (by setting it as output context with a lifespan of 0).

Florent.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Never even thought about this. Its working now.

Answer (score 0):

I actually wouldn't have expected that the followup intents would work the way you're trying. They're all followups to the original intent, rather than to each other. So it could be that the lifespan of the original intent's Context has expired by the third one. In this case, it would revert to the Fallback Intent.

But the reason for the error message itself is that you're not sending back a reply. If you're using a fulfillment, it means it isn't sending a reply. If you're not, it could be that the "Frostbite" Intent doesn't have a reply set or that your Fallback Intent doesn't have a reply set.